# Git Bash, getting local branch name

Tags: git, branch, githooks, ref, git-post-receive

Im trying to get on GIT POST-RECEIVE command the local branch name of computer, i tried the code 
"READ REF" but it outputs "ref/heads/branchname" i only want the branchname, can someone please help me trim using the output using bash command or is theres a specific code in git to get the local branchname of pushing user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

or

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

There's a difference for the two commands for `detached HEAD` state. The former shows an error message, while the latter one outputs the string `HEAD`.

For `bash` command, you can use `basename` to get the branch name.

```
branchname=`basename "ref/heads/branchname"`
```

Comment: Suggestion: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>/dev/null`, so that, when you're in detached-HEAD state, nothing is output, not even an error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

This one is what i need! branchname='basename "ref/heads/branchname"'